# How to use CMD in Dockerfile for a command that contains flag?

Tags: docker

How can I write the following command that contains a flag named `--checkpoint` using `CMD` in Dockerfile?

```
python3 --checkpoint /usr/src/app/logs-tacotron/model.ckpt-92000 /usr/src/app/demo_server.py
```

demo_server.py:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--checkpoint', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.checkpoint)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try CMD [ "python3" "--checkpoint /usr/src/app/logs-tacotron/model.ckpt-92000", ,"/usr/src/app/demo_server.py" ]

Comment: No. But trying now. I will inform you if it works.

Comment: It won't work, check the syntax in answer. We need to put each different element in inverted commas.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work

Comment: You should also just be able to put the word `CMD` at the front of the line, without converting it to the JSON-array form, if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this same format with flags also:

```
CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]
```

In your case:

```
CMD [ "python3", "--checkpoint", "/usr/src/app/logs-tacotron/model.ckpt-92000", "/usr/src/app/demo_server.py" ]
```

I tried:

```
CMD [ "ping", "-c", "2", "8.8.8.8" ]
```

and It worked!!

Comment: This doesn't work as `--checkpoint` is not a python standard option.

Comment: An edit has been made in question for clear convenience.